# Office addin loaded successfully but button implementation not working after deployment

Tags: c#, windows, ms-office, excel-addins

I am developing office add ins and developed it successfully and it is working on my development machine on every version of office.

Now when i tried to make deployment setup using install shield.

installed on other machine, all the required prerequisites installed and addin loads as i opened excel.

addin is showing under the tab, After clicking button must do the coded work but the button is not working.

i got the info about deploying setup from [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx).

am i missing something?

**EDIT**

Now i found that When i put addin release folder on other machine and tried to run .vsto file then it installs on machine and worked perfectly.

Now My question change to, how can I make setup which installs excel addin automatically on that machine on which I have installed it.

How to make it work?

Comment: Obviously, you have missed something. But to answer what it needs more detailed information what you have done.

Comment: i have modified the question. please tell me if any more details you will need.